# VirtualBox (Windows XP guest on Ubuntu host) through X11?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'd like to host a VirtualBox instance on my Ubuntu machine, using Windows XP as my Guest machine.   I'd like to know if I can use an X11 ZZZZZZZZ (`Xming/Putty/SSH -X`) to run VirtualBox on my Windows 7 machine remotely.

Also, if it is possible, could I disconnect from it (while it's still running) and reconnect to it from a different machine?

Comment: you'd probably be better off with a remote-desktop (RDP) straight to the guest OS, or using VNC, than trying to display the Vbox guest to a remote x-server.

Comment: Also, just to clarify ~quacks point, VirtualBox allows you to connect to the guest OS using RDP rather than connecting directly through the VBox application.

Comment: oh, duh.  dumb me!  u should put that as an answer so i can give u credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do to make my VirtualBox Windows XP install accessible from anywhere is the following.

I open a terminal window and open a new session with SCREEN.

I start my VirtualBox Windows XP machine using `VBoxHeadless --startvm "WindowsXP"`.
I detach from my screen session.
After a minute or two (the time it takes for Windows XP guest to load) I can RDP into Windows itself.

I have also installed www.logmein.com on the Windows XP guest so that I can access it from over the Internet.

I am using the Open Source Edition of VirtualBox on FreeBSD Host so I don't have the built-in RDP functionality mentioned in the comments elsewhere.

Also here is a good article that goes through steps for working with VirtualBox from the commandline.

http://www.kernelhardware.org/virtualbox-headless-vm/